# Why is this query not working in spqarql?

Tags: sparql

Im a very beginner in sparql, just started doint it a couple hours ago. Howewer, after some practicing i don't know why the following query is not working:

```
select * where
 {

?auth dbp:author  dbr:The_Lord_of_the_Rings .


} LIMIT 100
```

So basically i just want the author of this book, which is a property of it.

Comment: What is the error message or what other problem occurs. Which SPAQL endpoint do you use?

Comment: It's just gives back empty result.  Im using the dbpedia endpoint. (http://dbpedia.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```sql
select * where
{

 dbr:The_Lord_of_the_Rings dbp:author ?auth .

} LIMIT 100
```

**Update/Correction**:
The property `dbp:author` has the meaning: *has_author* (and **not**: *is_author_of* as it is implied by the positioning of subject and object in the question).

Comment: Ah, thank you, i need time to get used to this sparkql mindset.

Comment: why does it mean "is_author_of"? That is not true. The problem was just that in the triple pattern subject and object position were mixed up,

Comment: While writing my explanation I mixed it up myself. → corrected